# How can i fix discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "image" is not found error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to build a Discord bot that will send a screenshot from my computer when you type .image
I am using python

**My code**

```
import Discord
from discord.ext import commands
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Pokrenut")

@client.command()
async def image(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Borna\Desktop\Programiranje2\0.png'))
client.run("My token")
```

When I type .image in discord nothing happens but I get the error in terminal

```
Pokrenut
Ignoring exception in command image:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Borna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Borna\Desktop\Programiranje2\Discord.py", line 10, in image
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(r'C:\Users\Borna\Desktop\Programiranje2\0.png'))
NameError: name 'discord' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of this following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Borna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Borna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Borna\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'discord' is not defined
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "image" is not found
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "image" is not found
```

Comment: It looks like you have discord defined as `Discord` with a capital D and no where else is there a lower case d discord defined

Comment: That deosnt fix it

Comment: Please do `import discord` before calling `discord.File` in `async def image(ctx):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you imported `Discord`, but then you reference `discord` inside your image command. Try replacing `import Discord` with `import discord`.

I'm not exactly sure why it says "command image not found", probably a bug with discord.py and not handling the error correctly.